# XCode and App hangs while debugging

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.6

**Briefing:**

Application View Controller Stack:

```
Navigation Controller > RootViewController > TabbarController
```

Where RootViewController is a basic `UIViewController` (like a menu) and lets user to select the starting tab (`UIViewController`) for the upcoming `UITabbarController`.

**Occurance:**

- occurs on `iPhone 4S, iOS 5`
- not occurs on `iPhone 5, iOS 6`
- not occurs on any `simulator (iOS 5, 6)`

After I navigate to `UITabbarController` (which consists 4 `UIViewControllers`) if I try to change between tabs, App itself and XCode hangs for an indefinite time (between 5 to 60 seconds). I have disabled all background threads, all network traffic, every singleton. Yet it still hangs while debugging.

**This happens once per runtime, only on first change of tabs.**

The tricky part is if I disconnect my device from XCode and start app without debugging, there is no such behaviour. I tried to identify where this "hang" occurs. But I was unable to catch the thread/process which is causing it.

Looks like my app chokes during that period and `viewDidLoad,viewDidAppear,viewDidDisappear` messages starts to flow back in after hang is gone.

How can I address this problem, find out what is causing this?

I am using `XCode 4.6.1, iOS base SDK 6.1`. I have started this app on `XCode 4.3.2`, `iOS base SDK 5.1`. Then upgraded to `XCode 4.6.1` and this issue arised.

I also profiled the app for possible leaks, there is no leak and suspiciously app does not hang while profiling.

I am trying to address this issue for days now, it is getting a bit frustrating. I can provide any other details if requested.

Comment: Does it only occur if you have breakpoints?

Comment: no it happens even if I don't have breakpoints, but just for once. While app is unresponsive, I can't add any other breakpoints. XCode it self hangs as well.

Comment: Run the app along with activity monitor and check the memory usage of the program.

Comment: consumes nearly 30mb (real memory usage). Just to be clear, it does NOT hang while profiling, also not while using activity monitor.

Comment: I don't know how your XCode hangs, but if you can  you should "pause" (with the pause button, the same button you use to continue after a breakpoint) the project run from xcode and check what process/thread is running.

Comment: XCode becomes unresponsive. I cannot take action within that period of time, unforunately.

Comment: I need a breakpoint to identify when an app processes a background process and stucks there more than 1 or 2 seconds. In this point, I cannot identify the call stack, therefore the origin of the problem.

Comment: @Bartu, did You solve this problem?? I have a same problem and it is occuring while debugging too. I have no problem with simulators. XCode and app hanging between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods.